# How to reference a Widget in GWT UiBinder?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

**Is it possible to reference a UiBinder created widget and pass is to a setter of other widget in *.ui.xml file?**

I've tried following code to create a label (`CustomLabel`) that can listen to and follow the state of form widget (`CustomWidget`). The problem is that GWT compilation fails with:

```
[ERROR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
[ERROR]     at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeLoop(UTF_8.java:691)
[ERROR]     at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:579)
[ERROR]     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
[ERROR]     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
[ERROR]     at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
[ERROR]     at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
[ERROR]     at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:253)
[ERROR]     at java.io.PrintWriter.newLine(PrintWriter.java:482)
[ERROR]     at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:629)
[ERROR]     at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:740)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.log.PrintWriterTreeLogger.doLog(PrintWriterTreeLogger.java:79)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.log.PrintWriterTreeLogger.doCommitBranch(PrintWriterTreeLogger.java:65)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.log.AbstractTreeLogger.commitMyBranchEntryInMyParentLogger(AbstractTreeLogger.java:256)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.log.AbstractTreeLogger.branch(AbstractTreeLogger.java:167)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger.branch(TreeLogger.java:212)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.model.EditorModel.createEditorData(EditorModel.java:381)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.model.EditorModel.createEditorData(EditorModel.java:390)
[ERROR]     at com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.model.EditorModel.createEditorData(EditorModel.java:390)
```

*View.ui.xml*:

```xml
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <x:CustomLabel forTarget={widget} />
    <x:CustomWidget ui:field="widget" />
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

*View.java*:

```java
@UiField
CustomWidget widget;
```

*CustomLabel.java*:

```java
public void setForTarged(CustomWidget forTarget) {
    this.forTarget = forTarget
}
```

Comment: It turned out that the referencing to widgets using curly brackets works ok. The error with stacktrace above is related to wrong implementation of `IsEditor` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle this should work. I use similar references in my code.

In your View.java:

```
@UiField
CustomWidget customWidget;
```

should be

```
@UiField
CustomWidget widget;
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I actually managed to get it working in hello-world size project. Also thanks for the typo, I'll fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do it this way - no widget is available yet when your `setForTarget` method is called by UiBinder.

You can call this method in your code *after* your custom widget has been initialized.